# ERROR Write Text File after Read CSV

Tags: c#, csv

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\", "*.csv");

var fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\Redirect.txt", FileMode.Create);

var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream)
{
    AutoFlush = true
};

foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    string[] datacsv2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);

    foreach (string textcsv in datacsv2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(textcsv);
        Console.SetOut(streamWriter);
    }
}
Console.SetError(streamWriter);
```

Read and Write to txt.file one file header column don't save >> OK
but problem is Write to multi txt.file save header column since 2 file >> NOT OK

How to solve this problem?

Comment: example : File 1 in text file
17/06/15,23:15:00,Rain_Totaliser,%ML1,,124,124,,

multi file in text file
17/06/15,23:15:00,WaterLevelScaled,%ML3,,1.333332,1,,
17/06/15,23:15:00,RainLastLogPeriod,%ML12,,0,0,,
Date,Time,Var Nickname,Var Name,Var Description,Raw,Scaled,Units,
17/06/15,23:30:00,Rain_Totaliser,%ML1,,124,124,,

Comment: Are you getting issues with the writing to streamwriter?? its not clear.. only reason I think you might get issues with streamwriter if you called this a second time is you dont close it

Comment: As you have a string array and you don´t won´t to have the header row, why don´t you just iterate from 1 to datacsv2.length-1 ?

Comment: It is not really answering the OP but I would advice to not reinvent the wheel and use directly robust libraries instead, e.g. FileHelper http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: @SuradetLeelakiatwanich please add the infos of your comment directly into the question, indenting them well. Your comment is difficult to read.